# Android resources doesn't show unicode characters

Tags: android, android-studio, utf-8

I have been trying to develop Amharic app in Android studio and when inserting Amharic files in android values `strings.xml` it shows unreadable characters. I have tried UTF-8 encode and project file encoding but I can't fix it. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: share that string you added in string xml file

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with the editor where you are writing the characters. I have tried the Google translator and translated an English sentence to Amharic. Then copied the sentence and pasted it in the Android Studio which works perfectly fine.

Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I am sharing the File encoding settings of my Android Studio. You will find the settings in

Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Editor -> File Encoding

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @Raez Murshed I have tried the same word you have used from google translate but the some thing happen.Shall i see your file encoding setting?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the answer with the settings that I have. Please check your File encoding settings in Android Studio.